# Сортировка по слову

Tags: golang

Как в golang сделать сортировку строк по определенному слову строке?
Например чтобы набор строк

```
some text in string
some second text in string
some third text in string
```

сортировался по второму слову (`text`, `second`, `third`) соответственно и такой набор строк при сортировке по второму слову выдаст результат

```
some second text in string
some text in string
third text in string
```

Я написал только алгоритм который:

- разбивает набор строк на массивы в которых значение это целая строка,
- значения этих массивов разбивает на подмассивы в которых значение это слова
- в каждом подмассиве массива берется слово по целевому индексу, меняется местами с нулевым индексом,
- получившиеся массивы в которых значения это строки с измененным порядком слов, сортируются с помощью `sort.Slice()`,
- отсортированные массивы снова разбиваются на подмассивы в которых значения это слова в неправильном порядке,
- слово по нулевому индексу которое ранее было переставлено с целевого индекса, меняется местами с целевым индексом и таким образом возвращается нормальный порядок слов.
- формируется новая строка в которую конкатенируются отсортированные массивы.

Но с таким подходом работает не на всех наборах строк. Чаще возникает out of range, хотя я все обработал уже что можно было.

Как сделать сортировку по слову более адекватно? не могу инфу найти по этому поводу.

Answer (score 0):

Простой пример если я правильно понял

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
    "strings"
)

type sortStrByName []string

func (s sortStrByName) Len() int { return len(s) }
func (s sortStrByName) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return strings.Split(s[i], " ")[3] < strings.Split(s[j], " ")[3]
}
func (s sortStrByName) Swap(i, j int) { s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i] }

func main() {
    p := sortStrByName{
        "His name is Jake",
        "Her name is Alice",
        "His name is Dwane",
        "Her name is Felista",
        "His name is Bob",
    }
    sort.Sort(sortStrByName(p))
    for _, v := range p {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }

    s := []string{
        "some useless text in string",
        "some text in string",
        "third text in string",
        "some second text in string",
    }
// Сортировка по второму слову 
    sort.Slice(s, func(i, j int) bool { return strings.Split(s[i], " ")[1] < strings.Split(s[j], " ")[1] })
    for _, v := range s {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```